# Как импортировать модель данных в книге эксель в модель данных Power BI?

Tags: excel, powerbi

Как импортировать модель данных в книге эксель в модель данных Power BI? Я имею ввиду не просто данные, а и поля расчетные, которые уже были созданы в модели данных эксель.

Comment: Ок. Как? Просто импортировать файл ексель? Использовать стандартные методы и коннекторы? Или нужно докачивать аддоны и писать код?

Comment: Соответственно поменял ваш вопрос.